# re-enable/disable option values in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to re-enable back dropdown values? I only got the disabled part cause I do not know how to re-enable it back. I clicked 1000 on the startTime, so the endTime option values should be disabled until 1000. but when I clicked 0800 after that, it does not re-enable back from 0900 until 2000.
Please note that this is for update part..

## This is my code:

```
    Start Time:
    <select class="form-control" name="startTime" id="startTime">
    <option value="8" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "8") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0800</option>
    <option value="9" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "9") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0900</option>
    <option value="10" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "10") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1000</option>
    <option value="11" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "11") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1100</option>
    <option value="12" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "12") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1200</option>
    <option value="13" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "13") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1300</option>
    <option value="14" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "14") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1400</option>
    <option value="15" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "15") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1500</option>
    <option value="16" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "16") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1600</option>
    <option value="17" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "17") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1700</option>
    <option value="18" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "18") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1800</option>
    <option value="19" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "19") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1900</option>
    <option value="20" <?php if($row['StartTime'] == "20") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >2000</option>
    </select>

    End Time:
    <select class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endTime">
    <option value="8" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "8") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0800</option>
    <option value="9" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "9") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >0900</option>
    <option value="10" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "10") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1000</option>
    <option value="11" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "11") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1100</option>
    <option value="12" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "12") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1200</option>
    <option value="13" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "13") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1300</option>
    <option value="14" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "14") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1400</option>
     <option value="15" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "15") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1500</option>
    <option value="16" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "16") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1600</option>
    <option value="17" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "17") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1700</option>
    <option value="18" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "18") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1800</option>
    <option value="19" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "19") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >1900</option>
    <option value="20" <?php if($row['EndTime'] == "20") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >2000</option>
    </select>



     <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#startTime').change(function(e)
        {
          if($(this).val() == "8")
          {
            $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);

          }
          else if($(this).val() == "9")
          {
            $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
            $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          }
          else if($(this).val() == "10")
          {
            $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
            $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
            $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          }
        else if($(this).val() == "11")
        {
          $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "12")
        {
          $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "13")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "14")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "15")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "16")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '16']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "17")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '16']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '17']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "18")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '16']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '17']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '18']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else if($(this).val() == "19")
        {
         $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '16']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '17']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '18']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '19']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        else
        {
          $("#endTime option[value = '8']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '9']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '10']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '11']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '12']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '13']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '14']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '15']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '16']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '17']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '18']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '19']").prop('disabled' , true);
          $("#endTime option[value = '20']").prop('disabled' , true);
        }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Even if not a native speaker, I guess you can figure out what the opposite of `true` is in the English language ...?

Comment: so i need to put `false` on which statement?

Comment: If `.prop('disabled' , true)` disables a field, then …?

Comment: do I need to put  `.prop('disabled' , false)` on `else` part?

Comment: Yes, that does sound line a reasonable assumption :-)

Comment: And FYI, `.prop` can _set_ the value for every matched element in a jQuery element selection, so you don’t need a line for each individual option, you can re-enable them all in one go.

Comment: I already did as what you've told me but it does not re-enabling back after I change back the startTime input :(

Comment: You have options with values from 8 to 20 there, and you have an if condition for each and every single one of those values … so when exactly do you think the final else branch would ever come to execute …?

Comment: I just edit my codes

Comment: Now you only left lines that set options to disabled, and don’t have a single one any more that even tries to re-enable an option again …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Also, I made some changes to your code.

```
echo 'Start Time:';
echo '<select class="form-control" name="startTime" id="startTime">';

for($i = 8; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $time = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // Fills string with zeroes in front until it is 2 characters long, e.g. "08"
    $time = str_pad($time, 4, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT); // Fills string with zeroes in back until it is 4 characters long, e.g. "0800"

    if($row['StartTime'] == "$i") {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected="selected">' . $time . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $time . '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';

echo 'End Time:';
echo '<select class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endTime">';

for($i = 8; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $time = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // Fills string with zeroes in front until it is 2 characters long, e.g. "08"
    $time = str_pad($time, 4, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT); // Fills string with zeroes in back until it is 4 characters long, e.g. "0800"

    if($row['EndTime'] == "$i") {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '" selected="selected">' . $time . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $time . '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#startTime').change(function(e) {
    var selectedStartTime = $(this).val();

    $( '#endTime' ).children("option").filter(function() {
        return parseInt(this.value) <= selectedStartTime;
     }).prop("disabled", true);

    $( '#endTime' ).children("option").filter(function() {
        return parseInt(this.value) > selectedStartTime;
     }).prop("disabled", false);
  });
</script>
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/k7nowcmu/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `removeAttribute` to enable it again, I would recommend using `setAttribute` and simply setting `disabled` to `false`. Try `$("#endTime option[value = '8']").setAttribute('disabled', false)` instead. Repeat this for each option you would like disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense this by *a lot*, if you simply loop through the end time options, and check their position in the select field against the index of the selected start time option. End time options with an index position less than or equal to the currently selected start time option will be set to disabled, the rest enabled. (The condition expression `i <= idx` will result in either `true` or `false`, and then `disabled` is simply set accordingly.)

```js
$('#startTime').on('change', function() {
  var idx = $('#startTime')[0].selectedIndex;
  $('#endTime option').each(function(i) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', i <= idx);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    Start Time:
    <select class="form-control" name="startTime" id="startTime">
    <option value="8">0800</option>
    <option value="9">0900</option>
    <option value="10">1000</option>
    <option value="11">1100</option>
    <option value="12">1200</option>
    <option value="13">1300</option>
    <option value="14">1400</option>
    <option value="15">1500</option>
    <option value="16">1600</option>
    <option value="17">1700</option>
    <option value="18">1800</option>
    <option value="19">1900</option>
    <option value="20">2000</option>
    </select>

    End Time:
    <select class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endTime">
    <option value="8">0800</option>
    <option value="9">0900</option>
    <option value="10">1000</option>
    <option value="11">1100</option>
    <option value="12">1200</option>
    <option value="13">1300</option>
    <option value="14">1400</option>
    <option value="15">1500</option>
    <option value="16">1600</option>
    <option value="17">1700</option>
    <option value="18">1800</option>
    <option value="19">1900</option>
    <option value="20">2000</option>
    </select>
```